# Share clipboard data between users on multi-user (secondary space) Android?

Tags: multi-user, miui, copy-paste

Leaving security concerns aside, is there a reliable way to communicate data via clipboard between users on a single device without using network methods? For example just to copy a link in the primary space  and  then access it later via clipboard in the secondary space. App suggestions are welcome.

NB: There is already an option to import/export files,photos etc (but not clipboard sharing)

Running MIUI 9, Android 7

Comment: How about Chrome Tab Sync or TabCloud?

Comment: This secondary space implementation seems to differ in OnePlus devices. In my Android 10 on OnePlus 6, I can share clipboard between primary user apps, work profile apps, and parallel space apps. However, as expected, clipboards are not shared if user profiles are switched into using settings app.

Comment: IIRC SMS can be explored - by sending a SMS to yourself and accessing in other user. I haven't checked

Comment: Is MIUI's secondary space an implementation of multi-users or managed profiles (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)? // The app you are using to copy data copies *text*, *URI* or *intent* (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#Clipboard)? // Are you able to paste in primary space using the same app you are using in secondary space?

Comment: @IrfanLatif In MIUI there is a slightly different implementation of the feature, it is designed for users "to have their own apps, files, folders, photos, and so on", in this case app data and files aren’t shared between users, and one has to import/export the required files in order to access them. I can't paste directly between spaces

Comment: @beeshyams that is clever idea, it works even if private messaging is off, I can create a draft a message and can I access the "text" +1

Comment: @alecxs thanks hadn't tried that

Comment: @Firelord MIUI implementation seems different though since each user as a completely seperate space, and can't even share app data (although you can do it with apps)  max users is 2

Comment: @xavier_fakerat good. If it works you can post that as an answer!