# Firefox’s “Add to Home Screen”, but different profiles & privacy

Tags: home-screen, firefox-for-android

I have Firefox 68.9.0 on Android 8.1.0. Some websites allow one to add them to the home screen, a part of HTML5's Progressive Web App, and the website can then be viewed as if it's a real app, without the browser UI. However it shares the same regular Firefox cookies, so if I log into a site on regular Firefox, and open the “home screen” version, it's logged in there.

Is it possible to “add to home screen” and yet make it a different “profile”, so things are separated? This would allow me to (for example) add several twitter.com “apps” each logged in a different user. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible because cookies and home screen aren't shared across profiles AFAIK - an alternative could be to "share" that url and retrieve when in other profile? Choice of where to share would be dependent on what apps you are signed in from both profiles

Comment: Also see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222362/131553) question and comments - SMS to yourself may be an option, if that works